# How to use properly the ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity> in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

this is my simple DbContext inheriting class:

```
public class School : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Activity> Activity { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Activity>().Where(a => a.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
            s = entry.State.ToString();

        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Student>().Where(a => a.State != EntityState.Unchanged))

            s = entry.State.ToString();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

these are my entites:

```
 public class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Roll { get; set; }

    //naviagtional property
    public virtual IList<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}


 public class Activity
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double Maths { get; set; }
    public double Science { get; set; }
    public double History { get; set; }

    //navigational property
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

}
```

somewhere in my code i do this:

```
       int studentId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Student.id"]);
        Activity activity = dbContext.Activity.Where(e => e.Student.id == studentId).Single();
        activity.Student.Name = Request.Form["Student.Name"];
        activity.Student.Roll = Request.Form["Student.Roll"];
        activity.Maths = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["Maths"]);
        activity.Science = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["Science"]);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Everything's normal and fine and works as it should. My question is, by updating activity.Student.Name, how can I detect change in Activity entity and not in Student entity? Is there any support in Entity Framework to detect changes in the parent table (and not in the slave table, where actual change goes though).?? 
Please help, it will save me a lot of time..

Comment: But you didn't change activity. You changed student.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka please go through the question once more. I know I changed student, but i did it through Activity entity..so is there any way to detect change in activity?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an older question I thought I would give an answer anyway. **NO you cannot**.

The reasoning behind this is that you the programmer, as far as the code example goes is aware what is happening and could act on that (before doing the SaveChanges)  to make sure whatever you want to happen is going to happen.
The Student you are changing might also be part of other entities, so would you also want those entities to be notified. An automatic behavior as you suggest would result in very complex notifications begin sent through the model which is (in most cases undesirable).
As @Ladislav Mrnka also indicated youy did not change the activity, but a Student involved in the activity. If the student relation is more than a simple lookup perhaps the model should be changed. Form the sample code given it is hard to see "why" you would need to detect changes made "through" other entities